# Bank account in Seatle, Washington state

Tags: united-states, bank-account

My brother used to have a bank account more than 30 years ago in Seattle where he used to live. Being disable due to a car accident, he is unable to follow up the matter. He lives now in a nursing house in New York State. I learned from an old friend that the money in his account could have been frozen or transferred by the court in Seattle. I should appreciate your advice how to settle this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Search the [State of Washington website for unclaimed property.](http://ucp.dor.wa.gov/)

They will tell you everything you need to prove ownership.

Also there is never a charge for this. The third party sites you see want to to pay for a service the state already provides.

> Q. Do I have to pay a finder's fee?
>
> An asset locator, fee finder, or heir finder is a person or company
>   who charges a fee for helping owners receive their unclaimed property.
>   The fee is usually a percentage of the money due to the owner.
>
> Under Washington law, a finder may not charge a fee of more than 5% of
>   the property value. Owners and their heirs do not need to pay a
>   finder's fee to anyone to claim funds being held by the State of
>   Washington.